# Incorrect Rake Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Total beginner when it comes to Rails - been using this guide to help get started: http://createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-with-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/ and it all seems ok. I am wanting to use Postgresql but I'm having problems with my rake version.

When i try to create my database with:

```
rake db:create:all
```

...I'm getting the Rake aborted! message and telling me that i have activated 0.9.6 but my gemfile requires 10.1.0

I have found a few similar posts on here so I ended up trying:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

but this says the database does not exist - but that's what I'm trying to do in the first place.

Any ideas???

Comment: did you do bundle install?

Comment: yes and it show rake v 10.1.0 "Using rake (10.1.0)"

Comment: no reference to rake in my Gemfile. Or do you mean Gemfile.lock?

Comment: add it in your Gemfile and do bundle install again.

Comment: can you try this:  bundle exec rake db:create:all

Comment: same issue - when I bundle install it does reference rake and version 10.1.0 - isn't there a conflict of some sort that I need to resolve as I appear to be running 2 versions???

Comment: I ran: bundle exec rake db:create:all and message: [database name] already exists

Comment: hang on a minute - I now appear to be connected as I can see the rails welcome page! thanks

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
bundle exec rake db:create:all
```

Then

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: thanks - everything is working ok now - do you think I had set things up incorrectly or is this a common issue?

Comment: :) It is common. If you have more than one versions of rake gem in your system this will happen.